# adding Yammer app for SharePoint to a page

Tags: 2013, yammer

Is it possible to add `Yammer app for SharePoint` programmatically? and is it possible to configure it so that when you leave a comment only those that have access rights to the page could see the comment when they log on to Yammer? Because now when you write a comment to a page containing Yammer feed for SharePoint everybody in the Group can see the comment when they log on to Yammer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the app part programmatically just like any app part - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ocarpen/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-install-programmatically-an-app-in-sharepoint-2013-preview.aspx

I'm not sure I understand you security question, but if you want to narrow down who can see the yams, perhaps you should create individual groups for those sites.  With that being said, much more collaboration happens when we work in the open, so keeping groups open is preferred.

Comment: thanks, Is it possible to do it using CSOM. I am not allowed using c#. About the security question, it is not a good solution to have so many groups. If you create different sites for your projects and each site uses yammer to add comments to the pages so you have to have many yammer groups as sites (projects). and if you use same groups diferent persons can see other comments which belong to other projects.